# Can a Vulcan mind-meld with, or read the mind of, a Ferengi?

Tags: star-trek, telepathy

We have seen Spock mind meld or have telepathic contact with several aliens, including at least one extremely physiologically different (Horta).

[What humanoid species are immune to the Vulcan nerve pinch and the mind meld?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/67975/what-humanoid-species-are-immune-to-the-vulcan-nerve-pinch-and-the-mind-meld) claims that Ferengi are 'apparently immune' -- is there a source for this?

The answer to [Are there any species a Vulcan can't mind-meld with?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/58456/are-there-any-species-a-vulcan-cant-mind-meld-with) does not include Ferengi in the list of species with which a Vulcan can not mind meld, but the source is Memory Alpha.

Is there any canon source where a Vulcan actually attempts a mind meld with a Ferengi (and fails or succeeds), or which mentions that it is possible or impossible?

*If there is no canon source*, then I would be interested in answers from books.